# how to resolve push() method error in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
private void addCustomer(){
    String name = txtName.getText().toString();
    String address = txtAddress.getText().toString();
    String phone = txtPhone.getText().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
       String id = databaseCustomers.push().getKey();


    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "You Should enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

push method giving an error.how can i solbve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HVD6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
databaseCustomers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("cutomers");
```

to

```
databaseCustomers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = databaseCustomers.getReference("cutomers")
String id = ref.push().getKey();
```

So you need to call `push()` on a `DatabaseReference` object and not on a `FirebaseDatabase` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
databaseCustomers.child("customers").push().getKey(); //  databaseCustomers should be a database reference
```